# Passing a variable from PHP to a Flash SWF?

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3, variables

I'm trying to pass the file name of an image upload PHP script into Flash's UILoader component. So when a user uploads their image, the file name of the file is passed to flash so that the image displays within the Flash UILoader application.

Here's the PHP variable I'm trying to pass:

```
$filename= '';
```

And here's where Flash's UILoader gets it's source (ActionScript 3.0):

```
uiLoader.source = "freshly uploaded file.jpg ($filename)?";
```

So if anybody has any expert advice on how I'd going about doing this, that would be excellent. Thanks a lot in advance!

Aaron

Comment: I was going to suggest using `URLLoader` but I misread your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [FlashVars](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16417.html). You can then pass variables to the SWF when it's embedded.

Comment: This worked well while passing HTML variables, but I have a separate PHP that I need Flash to get the variable from. Thanks for the speedy response!

Comment: As in you have a .php file you need to call to get data from within the SWF?

Comment: Vice versa actually. The SWF needs the url of the uploaded file that the PHP file creates on upload (the image preview URL).